# Time-dependent Fourier Transform (TDFT)?

Tags: fourier-transform

In my DSP course we are learning right now about the Time-dependent Fourier Transform (TDFT), but I can't find any information about it online.

My professor said that it is similar to the Short-time Fourier Transform which I can find information about, except that whereas the STFT has a fixed signal and moving window, the TDFT has a moving signal and fixed window.

So does this TDFT usually go by a different name?

Comment: short-time FT, short-term FT, time-dependent FT. They are all the same, as far as I know.

Comment: just depends on if your perspective is moving along with the window or with the signal

Comment: Your professor make a simple thing complex by not explaining the incentive - To use FT you need to assume that the signal components are not changed during the measure. The size of the window is selected to allow the best extract of the desired signal.